# Base 64 Encoding XML to post to webservice

Tags: c#, .net, xml, base64

I am writing a service in C# .NET that takes some data, generates an XML string, and posts it to a webservice.

I have that working properly, but now I want to base64encode the XML string on the C# end and decode it in PHP on the webservice side.

Something is going wrong, because the decoding is not working as expected on the PHP side

On the PHP side I just do

```
$xml = trim(base64_decode($_POST['xmlpost']));
```

Which works fine from webservice to webservice.

Here is the C# code:

```
string xml = ###XMLHERE###;
WebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(liveURL);

//base 64 encode
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
string byteArrayEncoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xmlpost=" + byteArrayEncoded + "&test=1");

//send request
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
```

I know the XML format is correct because it works fine without encoding. What am I doing wrong?

Side note: after I fix this I am also trying to ensure that single quotes, double quotes and ampersands can be in the XML node text, if anyone can also help me with that.

[image]

Comment: "the decoding is not working as expected on the PHP side" - well what *is* happening? What value do you get in PHP?

Comment: when I print the "decoded" string it is garbled text, so it's not decoding properly

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                <ThirdPa\�\��[YO�ZX����Y[�
                                            �\�\��[Y@Р����77v�&A��ѵ������A���ݽɐ�4($$$�������������5�ѡ�����э����ѥ�����5�ѡ��
              </LoginB�H
                            �\�\�KVS

Comment: That sounds like the base64 isn't coming through properly. I suggest you log the base64 before you send it and before you decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 encoding uses characters like +, / and = that must be escaped in the URL encoded form data.  Something like this should yield better results for you.

```
string byteArrayEncoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
string byteArrayUrlEncoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(byteArrayEncoded);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xmlpost=" + byteArrayUrlEncoded + "&test=1");
```

Comment: whatabout on .Net framework 4 (not 4.5)?? I bet this works I just need a version for .NET 4

Comment: I believe the `UrlEncode` method is supported in .NET Framework 4.  See [HttpUtility Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility(v=vs.100).aspx).  Is it not?

Comment: It does say that online but I am having trouble referencing. I attached a screenshot of what Visual studio lists in my orig post

Comment: Hmm, it is not available in the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  It should work if you change the target framework of your project to .NET Framework 4.

Comment: I got it referenced. Will followup up about if it works

Comment: Will this also take care of the ampersands/single/double quotes?